# Google Cloud Endpoints Api call returning null

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-asynctask

I'm making an android app that uses a development server to respond api calls.

I set it up using the following guide:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints

I used the skeleton code provided by google on the example, so my api and the AsyncTask that peforms the calls look like this:

MyEndpoint class:

```
/** An endpoint class we are exposing */
@Api(
  name = "myApi",
  version = "v1",
  namespace = @ApiNamespace(
    ownerDomain = "backend.myapplication.madelenko.example.com",
    ownerName = "backend.myapplication.madelenko.example.com",
    packagePath=""
  )
)
public class MyEndpoint {

    /** A simple endpoint method that takes a name and says Hi back */
    @ApiMethod(name = "supplyJoke")
    public MyBean supplyJoke() {
        MyBean response = new MyBean();
        response.setData(JokeDispenser.getJoke());

        return response;
    }
}
```

MyBean Class:

```
/** The object model for the data we are sending through endpoints */
public class MyBean {

    private String myData;

    public String getData() {
        return myData;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        myData = data;
    }
}
```

The asyncTask:

```
public class FetchJokeTask extends  AsyncTask<Pair<Context,String>, Void, String> {
        private static MyApi myApiService = null;
        private Context context;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
            if(myApiService == null) {  // Only do this once
                MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                        new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                        // options for running against local devappserver
                        // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                        // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                        .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                        .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                            @Override
                            public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                                abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                            }
                        });
                // end options for devappserver

                myApiService = builder.build();
            }

            context = params[0].first;
            String name = params[0].second;

            try {
                return myApiService.supplyJoke().execute().getData();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}
```

For some reason, when I click a button and launch an AsyncTask, I get a 404 error. The toast returns html with the contents of a 404 page.

I used the debugger to find out why and I know that the asyncTask tries to execute this line and fails:

```
                return myApiService.supplyJoke().execute().getData();
```

Therefore, it returns an error message.

Is there anything wrong with my config?

Please help me to figure it out. Thanks.

P.S.: The problem is that the execute() method throws an IOException. I hope this extra piece gives you some context. Thank you very much.

Comment: return myApiService.supplyJoke().execute().getData();
why you having .getData(); extension after exucute(); its not needed i think

Comment: getData() is a method of the MyBean class that returns a String with its member variable. I need to call it because what I want to display in the toast is in fact a String containing the member variable of this object.

Comment: If you're running this locally, you can see in the console the URL it's trying to request - that should give you a clue if you're getting a 404.